# Is there a theory Sobolev space on Pseudo-Riemann and symplectic manifolds?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, manifolds

Pseudo-Riemmanian and symplectic manifolds appear in physics: in relativity theory, where the manifold have a non-positive definite metric but non-degenerate, and in mechanics as $T^*M$ is a natural symplectic manifold. In order to do analysis in the equations, we would like to have a theory of Sobolev space in these kinds of manifolds.

For example, consider the wave equation in an open set $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^2$:
$$ \partial_t^2 f-\partial_x^2 f=0 $$
(which is the Laplace equation with the Riemann pseudo-metric $g=dt^2-dx^2$)

Integrating by parts with a $\phi \in C^{\infty}_c $, it gives the "weak" equation:
$$ \int_{\Omega}dtdx \{\partial_t f \partial_t \phi- \partial_x f\partial_x\phi\}=0, \;\; \forall \phi \in C^{\infty}_c $$
We may consider the bilinear form in $C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$:
$$ B(f,g)=\int_{\Omega}dtdx \{fg+\partial_t f \partial_t g- \partial_x f\partial_xg\} $$
I would like to define the Sobolev space as a kind of Cauchy completion respect $B$. I don't know if this way is impossible or even $B$ is degenerate, (if it exists $f\not=0, \; B(f,g)=0$ forall $g$).

So, is there a theory of Sobolev space on pseudo-Riemann or symplectic manifolds?